# SeekBar se comportando de maneira inesperada ao mudar de uma aba para outra

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho um aplicativo com `ViewPager` e três abas (tabs), cada uma exibindo um *fragment* que eu procuro preservar na memória de forma que não sejam instanciados novos *fragments* a cada troca de aba/tela.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Fragmento0 mFragmento0 = null;
    private Fragmento1 mFragmento1 = null;
    private Fragmento2 mFragmento2 = null;


    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager viewPager) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int indice) {

        switch(indice){
        case 0:
            if (mFragmento0 == null) {
                mFragmento0 = new Fragmento0();
            }
            return mFragmento0;
        case 1:
            if (mFragmento1 == null) {
                mFragmento1 = new Fragmento1();
            }
            return mFragmento1;
        case 2:
            if (mFragmento2 == null) {
                mFragmento2 = new Fragmento2();
            }
            return mFragmento2;
        }
        return null;
    }

    ...
```

`Fragmento0` tem uma `SeekBar` com o valor padrão `60`, definido no layout do mesmo, e acima dela uma `TextView` informando o valor atual da `SeekBar`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="120"
    android:progress="60"/>
```

Este é o trecho relevante do `Fragmento0.onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_0, container, false);

    mTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mSeekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    mTextView.setText(mSeekBar.getProgress() + " minutos");

    ...
}
```

Quando troco de aba, percebo que a `SeekBar` se comporta de maneira estranha: quando altero seu valor para ficar diferente do padrão e mudo da aba 0 para aba 1, ao voltar para a aba 0 o valor se mantém, o que é esperado. Porém quando mudo da aba 0 para a aba 2, ao voltar para a aba 0 a posição da `SeekBar` não muda mas o `TextView` volta a indicar o valor padrão `60`.

Debugando o código descobri que `Fragmento0.onCreateView()` não está sendo chamado no primeiro caso, o que eu acredito ser o esperado, mas está sendo chamado no segundo. Por quê? Eu não faço nenhuma transação com os *fragments*, não movo nenhum para o *back stack* por exemplo.

De acordo com o ciclo de vida dos *fragments*, está certo isso acontecer? Como faço para corrigir esse comportamento? Teria que usar `onSaveInstanceState()`? (tentei e não funcionou). Mas por que em um caso a view é recriada e no outro não? E por que a chamada a `onCreateView()`, ao fazer `inflate` no layout, não restaura o valor padrão da `SeekBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João Vitor, esse comportamento do `ViewPager` está correto.

O `ViewPager` sempre destrói a View, porém mantem o Fragment com o estado salvo, vide o valor default 1 do [`OffscreenPageLimit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getOffscreenPageLimit%28%29). Ele guarda apenas um Fragment que está fora de visão, o último que foi visto, por isso que ao chegar no terceiro `Fragment`, ele destrói o primeiro.

No seu caso, há duas soluções:

1. Setar o `offscreenPageLimit` do `ViewPager` para 3 ou quantos quiser, isso evita a destruição da `View`. O que traz um benefício se a carga da `view` for lenta, e o malefício de que essa `View` ficará na memória.
2. Implementar o `onSaveInstanceState` salvando todo o estado da tela, e no `onCreateView` usar o `savedInstanceState` para restaurar o estado novamente. Vendo a documentação do [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), ele diz que o estado salvo no `onSaveInstanceState` estará disponível no `onCreateView`.

Em relação a sua última pergunta, os `Fragments` por padrão salvam seu estado quando alguma configuração da `Activity` muda (rotação por exemplo), assim como descreve o atributo [`retainInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29). Não sei se no seu caso houve rotação da tela quando percebeu esse problema, consegue descrever um caso em que isso sempre ocorre? Acredito que seja o caso de realizar uma outra pergunta talvez, não tenho certeza.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta. Setar o offscreenPageLimit funcionou. Estou forçando o aplicativo a não rotacionar a tela, porém não entendi sua recomendação sobre minha última pergunta, pois meu antepenúltimo parágrafo descreve a situação em que o problema sempre ocorre. Além disso, onSaveInstanceState não parece funcionar porque o fragmento não chega a ser destruído (onDestroy chamado), somente sua view.

Comment: A sua última pergunta, acredito eu, que envolve a questão do RetainInstace que ocorre por trás dos "panos" e que salva o estado sem o desenvolvedor precisar fazer nada. Mas sobre isso eu não tenho certeza porque nunca precisei usar, e as vezes ja me atrapalhou. No seu caso, não sei se é isso que causa o problema do valor padrão (não aparecer) ao reconstruir a view. Seria bom investigar analisando o Bundle do estado salvo.

Comment: Complementei meu comentário anterior incluindo minha experiência com o onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: Esse problema do `onSaveInstanceState` não ser chamado talvez faça sentido como falou, mas ai tem que ver como salvar o estado nesse caso... Posso dar uma olhada e atualizar minha resposta.

Comment: Vou aceitar a resposta de qualquer forma pois o problema foi resolvido, porém se tiver com que complementar sua resposta em relação a esse problema, agradeceria.

Comment: Irei dar uma olhada e em breve complemento minha resposta.