# Recuperar dados do fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho uma Activity com 4 tabs, em cada tab carrego um Fragment diferente, em cada fragment tenho um fomulario, e no ultimo tenho o botão de Cadastrar, quando clicar em Cadastrar quero pegar os dados de todos os outros fragments, pensei em criar uma classe com os dados do formulario e cada vez que passo de fragment vou armazenando em um objeto e passando de fragment pra fragment, porem não sei onde vou alimentar esse objeto, ja tentei no metodo onPause porem não da certo pois o fragment não é pausado ao acessar o outro.

Eu coloquei um onPause em cada Fragment pra testar.

```
public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
Log.i("PAUSE", "pause A");
}
```

Os logs do Fragmente A, o B, o C e D são iguais só mudando o pause A/B/C/D. Porem o que acontece é o seguinte, quando navego entre as tabs, ele aparece a informação do onPause não do que foi pausado, mas sim do anterior. Por exemplo, estou na A, passo pra B nada acontece, quando passo pra C, aparece no Log, "teste A", quando passo pro D aparece "teste B". E pra voltar também é a mesma coisa, quando vou do D pro C nada acontece. Ai do C pro D aparece "pause D"

Activity

```
package br.com.android.controledevisitas.view;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.R;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.adapter.ViewPagerAdapter;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.fragment.RealizaVisitaFragmentA;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.fragment.RealizaVisitaFragmentB;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.fragment.RealizaVisitaFragmentC;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.fragment.RealizaVisitaFragmentD;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.model.Visita;

public class RealizarVisitaActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    public Visita visita = new Visita();

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, RealizarVisitaActivity.TabInfo>();
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    public String teste;

    // Informação da Tab
    private class TabInfo {
        private String tag;
        private Class<?> clss;
        private Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.clss = clazz;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    // Um simples factory que retorna View para o TabHost
    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Infla o layout
        setContentView(R.layout.realizavisita);
        // setContentView(R.layout.realizarvisita_a);
        // Inicializa o TabHost
        this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Define a Tab de acordo com o estado salvo
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
        // Inicializa o ViewPager
        this.intialiseViewPager();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // salva a Tab selecionada
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void intialiseViewPager() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,
                RealizaVisitaFragmentA.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,
                RealizaVisitaFragmentB.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,
                RealizaVisitaFragmentC.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,
                RealizaVisitaFragmentD.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        RealizarVisitaActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("A"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo(
                "Tab1", RealizaVisitaFragmentA.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RealizarVisitaActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("B"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo(
                "Tab2", RealizaVisitaFragmentB.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RealizarVisitaActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("C"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo(
                "Tab3", RealizaVisitaFragmentC.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        RealizarVisitaActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("D"), (tabInfo = new TabInfo(
                "Tab4", RealizaVisitaFragmentD.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    private static void AddTab(RealizarVisitaActivity activity,
            TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        // Attach uma Tab view factory para o spec
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        // Avisa para o mViewPager qual a Tab que está ativa
        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
package br.com.android.controledevisitas.adapter;

import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
     private List<Fragment> mFragments;

      public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);

        mFragments = fragments;
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int i) {  
        return mFragments.get(i);
      }

      @Override 
      public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
      }
}
```

Comment: Esta usando o `ViewPager` para mostrar os `Fragments`?

Comment: Sim estou, fiz seguindo esse tutorial aqui. http://wcabralti.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/tabs-fragments-swipe-em-android.html

Comment: Assim eu consegui passar os dados ja, mas assim, pra pegar tudo eu tenho q completar, ai pra pegar os dados da 3a aba tenho que voltar na 1a, ai depois vou pra 4a e cadastro, se eu ir direto ele fica sem os dados da 3a. :/

Comment: O problema da perda de dados é por causa do comportamento do `ViewPager`, de uma olhada nessa pergunta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16682/seekbar-se-comportando-de-maneira-inesperada-ao-mudar-de-uma-aba-para-outra/16706#16706) onde eu explico um pouco o comportamento do `offsetPageLimit`. Os dados do `Fragment` você pode obter através do `Adapter` que usou no `ViewPager`, acesse a `View` do `Fragment` para pegar os dados.

Comment: Desculpa mas programo em android a menos de 1 mes, como vou fazer pra usar o Adapter do ViewPager.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e inclua o código de sua `Activity`. Onde instância o `Adapter` e também o código do `Adapter`.

Comment: pronto, atualizado

Comment: Olá boa! Prezados estou com o mesmo problema de uma tela com Tabs e com dificuldade para pegar os varios campos em cada fragment, conforme o Wakin mencionou eu tento pegar os dados usando o adapter mais recebo um NullPointerException, coloquei uma pergunta aqui no forum, infelizmente não houve resposta e estou tendo que comentar aqui na esperança de ter um norte do que esta havendo, não vejo como usar Interfaces que é o recomendado na documentação de Tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para entender melhor porque o `onPause` do `Fragment A` só é chamado quando vai para o `Fragment C`, vou tentar explicar o comportamento do `ViewPager`.

O ViewPager, por padrão, só guarda em memória 2 itens. O que está visivel e o próximo, para o efeito de transição ser mais fluído.

O atributo [`OffscreenPageLimit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) controla esse efeito, por padrão ele é 1.

Se no seu caso os `Layouts` forem simples, você pode setar ele como 3, para que nenhum dos seu `Fragments` seja destruído.

Para o problema da perda de dados, existem duas formas de abordar o problema:

1. Setar o `OffscreenPageLimit` do `ViewPager` para 3, assim nenhum `Fragment` será destruído. E os dados não serão perdidos. Bastando acessar os `Fragments` pelo `Adapter` para recuperar os dados. **Reforço que essa só é uma boa alternativa se os Layouts não forem complexos, para não haver gasto excessivo de memória**
2. Quando o `Fragment` for destruído e, isso é, quando o método `onDestroyView` for chamado. Basta salvar os dados na `Activity`. No seu `Fragment` teria algo como:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDestroyView() {
       // Usar o método findViewById, pegando os dados que for de interesse
       // Nesse caso há duas formas:
       //  1. Acessar a instância da Activity com getActivity(), fazer um cast e ir setando os dados.
       ((SuaActivity) getActivity()).salvarDados(...);
       //  2. Criar um Listener, setar e chama-lo nesse momento passando os dados
       mSaveStateListener.salvarDados(...);

       super.onDestroyView(); // Chamar o metodo da superclasse
   }
   ```

   A segunda forma envolve: Criacao de uma interface `Listener`, setar um `Listener` em cada `Fragment` através da `Activity`. Esse `Listener` será chamado para salvar os dados quando o `Fragment` for destruído.

Para acessar os `Fragments` que estão no `Adapter`, e recuperar os dados do formulário, você poderá fazer desse modo dentro da activity:

```
public void confirmaFormulario() {
    RealizaVisitaFragmentA visitaA = mAdapter.getItem(0);
    RealizaVisitaFragmentB visitaB = mAdapter.getItem(1);
    // Mesma coisa com os demais fragmentos

    // Chama os metodos do Fragment para recuperar os dados
}
```

Esse método deverá ser chamado quando o botão que está no `Fragment 4` for clicado.

Comment: Se tiver alguma dúvida, é só falar que eu detalho mais o ponto.

Comment: Tem que garantir que o `Adapter` foi criado. Onde colocou esse código? Como esta o tratamento do clique no botão do ultimo `Fragment`?

Comment: Desculpe, eu estava viajando aqui, ja consegui, desculpe pelo incomodo. E muito obrigado por tudo :)